# Match line breaks with regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, regex, parsing

I googled this and looked on here and none of the answers seem to match the right thing for me. They seem to mostly return `null`. I'm trying to search a CSS files with it with a CSS block like:

```
.twitterfeed p {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: #373737;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0 10px 20px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 13px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px
}
```

I didn't make the CSS file or anything so I don't know whats in it and I dont know if there will be new lines or single liners like: `body { background:color; }`

How can I match that entire block, but not other blocks? So, from `something { }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = '.twitterfeed p {\
    background: #fff;\
    border-radius: 15px;\
    color: #373737;\
    font-size: 15px;\
    margin: 0 10px 20px 10px;\
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;\
    padding: 13px;\
    position: relative;\
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px\
}';

var matches = str.match(/([^{]+\{[^}]+\})/g);
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/E9auH/)

Comment: @Brian: Prove it! I think [it works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/FfLKm/). I would like to see an example of yours which proves otherwise.

Comment: @Brian Seems to work for me: http://regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=(%5B^{%5D%2B%5C{%5B^}%5D%2B%5C})&input=.twitterfeed%20p%20{%0A%09background%3A%20%23fff%3B%0A%09border-radius%3A%2015px%3B%0A%09color%3A%20%23373737%3B%0A%09font-size%3A%2015px%3B%0A%09margin%3A%200%2010px%2020px%2010px%3B%0A%09-moz-border-radius%3A%2015px%3B%0A%09padding%3A%2013px%3B%0A%09position%3A%20relative%3B%0A%09-webkit-border-radius%3A%2015px%0A}

Comment: @Shef - you're absolutely right - edit your answer so I can change my vote.  Completely my misunderstanding on JavaScript's multiline mode...

Comment: @Brian: My answer is fine the way it is. I used the variable so the OP could see where the var `str` came from. However, even with backslashes the line breaks will be preserved. So, there is no point in thinking it wouldn't work with "real" line breaks.

Comment: @Shef - I what I mean is, I downvoted your answer, which I can undo if you make an edit to your post.  I agree that your answer was correct and based on the pseudo linebreak usage I assumed you were getting a false positive without multiline enabled.

Comment: @Brian: Oh sorry, I misunderstood you. Forgot about that restriction. :) Just edited it!

Comment: @Shef - all good, and my apologies for downvoting a solid answer!

Comment: Why did you escape the curly brackets in the expression?

Comment: @dtanders: Because they will be used as quantifiers if they are not escaped. For example if you want to match only a two digit number you would do `[0-9]{2}`. Scroll down to the bottom of the [regex reference table](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) to read about the quantifiers. In the OP's case they should be literally matched, not used as quantifiers.

Comment: They only get used as quantifiers if they contain a valid quantifier range.  I can see how it might speed up the parser and disambiguate their meaning in the expression to escape them though, so good thinking.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use something like

```
{[\S\s]*?}
```

Because Javascript does not know the dotall modifier `s` to make the `.` matches newlines you have to search for `[\S\s]*` that means match a nonwhitespace character (`\S`) or a whitespace character (`\s`) zero or many times.

I made it a non greedy match `*?` to avoid matching the last `}`

See it here [online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2udte)

Answer (score 0):

```
/\w+\s*{[^}]+}/
```

Finds simple CSS blocks when I try it on a multiline string.  You'd have to add some characters to the capture group on the front of it to represent all of the possible tags and selector flags, though.

```
/[\w\*\.#>@ \t]+\s*{[^}]+}/
```

Might work for most tags but it's off the top of my head and I might be missing some flags.

More about the limitations of the JS regular expression language, if you're interested http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Comment: Hmm, for that CSS block it seems to match from the `p` to the closing `}` but not the .twitterfeed:

http://regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=%5Cw%2B%5Cs*{%5B^}%5D%2B}&input=.twitterfeed%20p%20{%0A%09background%3A%20%23fff%3B%0A%09border-radius%3A%2015px%3B%0A%09color%3A%20%23373737%3B%0A%09font-size%3A%2015px%3B%0A%09margin%3A%200%2010px%2020px%2010px%3B%0A%09-moz-border-radius%3A%2015px%3B%0A%09padding%3A%2013px%3B%0A%09position%3A%20relative%3B%0A%09-webkit-border-radius%3A%2015px%0A}

Comment: I don't know how that regex pal site works, but it works in my browser's regex engine: [link](http://jsconsole.com/?'.twitterfeed%20p%20%7B%5Cnfart%3A%20toot%5Cn%7D'.match(%2F%5B%5Cw%5C*%5C.%23%3E%40%20%5Ct%5D%2B%5Cs*%7B%5B%5E%7D%5D%2B%7D%2F)%3B)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want what's between the curly brackets:

```
var m = myCssFileString.match(/\{[^\}]+\}/m);
```

The match will include the brackets - you can easily substring and trim to get just the defined styles.

Comment: I need to also capture the selectors because im trying to find exact dupes since there are literally exact dupes form copy & pasting.